# Loading an array with a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to load a small 1D array using a for loop and for some reason I'm not getting the correct output.

```
int main()
{
  const int ROW = 3;
  int Table[ROW];
  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
  {
    Table[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i ++)
  {
    std::cout << Table[i] << std::endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

The return I'm getting on my console is

```
0
0
1716919432
```

I would think that the output would be `0 1 2` (with the newline of course). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `Table[i];` - That line doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure what to do to it.

Comment: You never initialized the array, so the value of each element is garbage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Table[i];
```

That line doesn't do anything at all.  I assume you meant:

```
Table[i] = i;
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.